# Knockout Cart Editor Example questions : extending cascading drop-downs with nested arrays and functions

Tags: arrays, data-binding, nested, knockout.js, shopping-cart

Here's [my fiddle attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/dunderjeep/mVNr8/16/) combining code on the Knockout cascading Cart Editor live example on the Knockoutjs.com site, and with RP Niemeyer's example of [data binding nested arrays](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/VUfSS/)  to try and achieve a cascading cart extended with product options in the functional format given by Niemeyer.

1. Why doesn't the quantity field update the subtotal?
2. Why doesn't 'Remove' work?
3. Why does formatCurrency(price) produce a 'unable to parse bindings' error?
4. Why does it happen that changing the product field doesn't update the price but if 'Add Product' button is pressed the change will appear in the next line?
5. In Niemeyer's example 'add-product' and is a methods inside the scope of the functions rather than the cartLine, which I copied for the 'subtotal' method - which is the better place to handle these operations?

Thanks to the work of S.Sanderson, R.P.Niemeyer, J.Papa for their incredible effort in the community to promote Knockout.  It's awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, so your fiddle is a bit more complicated than it needs to be, but I have tried to leave the structure alone in case you were planning to expand. I do have a few questions though, but I'll get to those at the end. First, your questions:

1. You had several quantity and subtotal properties, one on each object (line, category, and product). Your layering had confused them (and me, honestly). I removed the extra quantity and subtotal properties on your models, the didn't really make sense anyway, but I left them in your data. Your should really sort out what you want this to look like.
2. Your layering was wrong, the removeLine was looking for a function on the cartLine, and sending the product, but you had the function on the viewmodel and needed the cartLine. Moving the remove line to the outermost context fixed this.
3. I didn't get this error.
4. Your price was not getting update properly. This was a context-layering issue.
5. I think you linked to the wrong fiddle for Niemeyer, the one you linked has no product in it.

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaUQm/1/) for your code. It's still a bit messy because, again, I tried not to mess with more than I needed to. You really should consider restructuring the data and/or viewmodels though, it doesn't need to be this complex. I removed some of the layering though, since it didn't match your viewmodel.

Also, your category.subscribe method was INSIDE the computed observable for subtotal. I moved it outside, onto the model.

NOTE: I am using knockout2.0 in the fiddle. Please consider updating. Knockout1.3Beta does not implement control flow in the same way, and this was causing a seperate error I didn't talk about.

So, my questions:

1. Why is there a quantity on both product and options in the data and object defintions?
2. Why is there a subtotal on each of product, category and cartLine?
3. Why is there a grandtotal on menu and viewmodel?
   3a. Why is there a grandtotal on menu at all? This makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you very much @Tyrsius ! A great example to study.  Sorry about the confusion - I'm still trying to figure out the best way to model everything - so that is why subtotal, grand-total and quantity are showing up under different scopes.  Later, product Options will take quantities.  I liked Niemeyers eg, this OOP approach seemed most extensible - each object/node handling it's own subtotal and quantity, but it gets confused for me with CartLine as to who's job it is.  It maybe wrong but I want the UI to be as anonymous as possible building itself from the JSON it gets from the server.

Comment: @user1245219 That's going to get very difficult, and Knockout was designed for an MVVM approach. Your viewmodel (knockout objects), should be tailored to the view (your page). While it is possible to use a value on your JSON to select a template dynamically, it still requires the template to fit the properties it will bind too. Don't try to be so flexible that you are no longer cohesive! Also, if my answer is helpful, consider upvoting it (it took me a while to sort out your fiddle =P).

Comment: I will follow your advice.  Thank you for taking the time and your helpful response; I tried to upvote but it said I don't have enough reputation points - shows what a noob I am.  When I get the reputation I promise to come back to this :)

Comment: @user1245219 lol, I forgot they wouldn't let you upvote. No worries, good luck with your app.